# pointer being freed was not allocated -- how to debug in Xcode objective c?

Tags: debugging, memory-management, ios6, nsdictionary

I need some help understanding how to use the debugging tools -- the previous posts on this topic suggest using NSZombie and setting breakpoints. These are not working for me, meaning I don't understand how to use them properly -- or how to interpret what they are telling me.

(I'm operating in a vacuum, basically -- no one in my workplace or social circle does objective c programming...)

Here's the offending code. My idea is to make moving array of 100 objects. The routine motionDataArray is called by the motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame method. The array gets populated and when its length reaches 100 it has the first object removed so there will always only ever be 100 objects in the array. This way, I figure, I can take the mean of the data and get rid of a lot of the noise.

(I imagine there is probably a better way to achieve this goal, but here is what I've come up with...)

```
- (void) motionDataArray: (CMCalibratedMagneticField) field
{
    NSDictionary *motionData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: motionManager.deviceMotion.gravity.x],@"gravity_x",                                            
        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: motionManager.deviceMotion.gravity.y],@"gravity_y",
        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: motionManager.deviceMotion.gravity.z],@"gravity_z",
        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: field.field.x],@"mag_x",
        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: field.field.y],@"mag_y",
        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: field.field.z],@"mag_z",
        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: `enter code here`locationManager.heading.magneticHeading],@"mag_heading",
        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll],@"roll",
        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw],@"yaw",
        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch],@"roll",
        nil];


        //NSLog(@"%d",[motionArray count]);


        if([timerArray count] > arrayCount - 1)
        {
            int i = [timerArray count] - arrayCount;
            for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
            {
               [motionArray removeObjectAtIndex:0]; 
            }
        }


    [motionArray addObject:motionData];

}
```

The code runs fine for the first two hundred iterations or so, and then comes the crash and the error: pointer being freed was not allocated.

Any good pointers on how to interpret the output from Instruments or anyother debugging methodology would be great help for me, and I'm sure for others out there too. Many thanks in advance...

Tim Redfield

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have a solution -- it runs without crashing and the array stays at the 100 maximum. But, I don't really understand WHY it works. It seems the array cannot have an object removed from it, unless @synchronize is used, as follows:

```
if([timerArray count] > arrayCount - 1)
{
    int i = [timerArray count] - arrayCount;
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
    {
        @synchronized(timerArray) {
            [timerArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this has to do with the array having an object removed before it is allocated, which seems to happen because the code loop is not necessarily running at the same speed as the motionManager is pushing the data. I am still trying to wrap my head around this. Comments welcomed!